# axios get multiple id parameter issue

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-redux, axios, react-hooks

I am newbie for react app. I am fetching the details of data based on some parameters like start date, end date and serial numbers. I am passing multiple serial numbers as separated with comma value in string with the usage of axios.get method. My query is like below.

```
  var formattedstartTime = moment(startTime)
    .utc()
    .format()
    .toString();
  var formattedendTime = moment(endTime)
    .utc()
    .format()
    .toString();

  const modemSerialsValues = networks.map((p) => p.modemSerial).join(",");
  //const modemSerialsValues="161887,162181,136787,141300,153700,156282,160219,157249,160124,204883,204707,209266,156881,157944,157532,208788,137311,157971,160131,208972,162157,153436,209377,160010,204915,162045,131292,160136,160014,204630,209508,235133,130508,209413,160078,204949,159977,236148,204718,137920,171014,160110,161295,157706,160185,130220,74699,130033,224303,272,153264,136696,129740,162017,153243,160017,159743,132118,157570,160180,159942,154105,155613,156030,161283,155940,74931,136773,159732,157694,161153,160089,156202,204859,209440,230476,131772,160176,156795,209514,130401,209445,224114,156243,235016,209224,130436,159927,223996,161813,70932,209292,136529,209172,209397,160111,72434,209281,161441,136556,136794,160040,162023,153160,156315,158076,152777,171375,224297,224277,70704,129496,224220,224220,159856,209418,74575,156908,84691,70704,157856,70912";

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setPerformanceLvls(null));
    axios
      .get(
        config.API_PERFORMACE + `/${formattedstartTime},${formattedendTime}`,
        { data: '"' + modemSerialsValues + '"' }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        const pd: PerfomanceData[] = res.data;
        console.log("++++++++++++Pd+++++++++++++");
        console.log(pd);
        console.log("++++++++++++Pd+++++++++++++");
        const pdMap = pd.reduce((acc, curr) => {
          acc[curr.deviceSerialNumber] = curr;
          return acc;
        }, {});
        setData(pdMap);

        const plvlMap = pd.reduce((acc, curr) => {
          acc[curr.deviceSerialNumber] = curr.perfomanceLevel;
          return acc;
        }, {});

        console.log(plvlMap);

        dispatch(setPerformanceLvls(plvlMap));
        setDataFetched(true);
        console.log(pdMap);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("can not load data");
        //setErrorMessages(["Cannot load data"])
        //setIserror(true)
      });
  }, [dispatch, endTime, formattedendTime, formattedstartTime, modemSerialsValues, startTime]);
```

** But getting 204, I didn't get why and it is taking more time as expected. Ideally it should call within miliseconds but taking almost 20 min to get 204 value.**

I tried to get the data by post as well but timing is the major concern. in Post as well it is taking more time.

Comment: Did you try Postman, etc? Maybe the reason for the issue is back-end, need to be sure.

Comment: You said you're a newbie, therefore here some information on why you shouldn't use the `var` keyword anymore: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/stop-using-var-to-declare-variables-in-javascript-6c0caec16f43

Answer (score 0):

204 doesn't mean that it failed. It means No Content. So maybe you have made a mistake in backend..